# How to send secure url from Angular 8 to spring boot controller?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, pipe, href

I'm trying to hit the controller from the template, my http client calls are automatically
added token but this link doesn't work, so I tried to add pipe in order for it to
make httpClient call but it doesn't work.

I have the following template in Angular 8 app:

```
<a href="MY_API + '/my/url/' + myId | secureLink | async" target="_blank">Download PDF</a>
```

This is the pipe:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'secureLink'
})
export class SecureLinkPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
    transform(url): Observable<SafeUrl> {
        return this.http
            .get(url, { responseType: 'text' })
            .map(val => this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(val)));
    }
}
```

If the pipe was working correctly I supposed to hit the controller:

```
@GetMapping("/my/url/{myId}")   
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> generatePDF(@PathVariable("myId") String myId) {
```

Without pipe I was able to reach the JWT filter but it is null of course. Can you help
with tranforming the url to http client call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpInterceptor` only works with `HttpClient` method calls. Anchor links wouldn't get intercepted so wouldn't have the auth token added

You can create a `link button` or intercept the anchor click (an anchor with no href) and call the API from the click handler

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not from your pipe. It's from how you use it. This line is wrong:
`<a href="MY_API + '/my/url/' + myId | secureLink | async" target="_blank">Download PDF</a>`

You're using a normal text. What you needed to do is to bind the value to the href attribute.

- Normal text: `href="1+1"` => result: href="1+1", literal, nothing change
- Binding: `[href]="1+1"` => result: href="2"

So to fix the issue, this is what you should use:
"<a **[href]**="MY_API + '/my/url/' + myId | secureLink | async" target="_blank">Download PDF"

Comment: [hred] didn't workm this is why I removed the [] I'll try tomorrow thw (click) option (without pipe

Comment: That's the way angular's binding works so if it doesn't it must have a reason, you could share the error or post your code in a stackblitz, we can take a look together